# Identical fstab options end up with different permission

Tags: mount, fstab, automounting

I recently attached a SSD to my system, with the old HDD in the DVD drive bay I set up the file mount option in the /etc/fstab file.

The permissions are as follows
for SSD:

```
/dev/sda2   /home/arun/SSD/     auto rw,user,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show   0 0
```

for HDD

```
/dev/sdb2   /home/arun/HDD/     auto rw,user,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show   0 0
```

The differnce is the HDD do not give me any write permissions unless i am operating as root.

What I tried:

1. using '**sudo chmod 777 /home//HDD**' to change the permissions. command passes correctly but nothing reflects in action(root permission still needed), file permissions do not get a 'w' when i do 'ls -l'
2. using '**sudo chown  /home//HDD**' , error: operation not permitted.

I was able to write to this HDD, before I cleaned both my disks and Installed the operating system Ububntu 16.04 LTS.

both the commands were run recursively and non-recursively.

Can This be due to  the fact that I installed it in the DVD drive bay? Do I need to change something in the BIOS setting?

Comment: Post the output of `lsattr /home/arun/HDD`. Also, it may be better to create an`SSD` and `HDD`directory in `/mnt` and change your `/etc/fstab` to mount the drives there rather than mounting them in your home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run from root this command:

```
chown -R arun:arun /home/arun/HDD
```

and after try to write something in it.

Comment: already tried, same error: **operation not permitted**

Comment: is that an fat16 or fat32 or exfat filesystem? if yes they can't handle permissions.

Comment: NTFS won't take the permissions either.

Comment: yes you are right, you have to set permission on mount. something like this : /dev/sda2   /home/arun/HDD/     auto rw,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show   0 0

Comment: thanks @D'ArcyNader it was a FAT32 partition, now formatted to ext4. problem gone now.